# Call callback inside another one

Tags: java, gwt

can you please suggest me, how can i call inside of first AsyncCallback after calling on Success, the second AsyncCyllback? i use gwt rpc and load my data into ui, and after calling this first AsyncCallback on Success method i must call another AsyncCallback that execute the next part of the first AsyncCallback and load data from db into ui:

```
void show(int last) {

    AsyncCallback<List<C>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<C>>() {


        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

        }

        public void onSuccess(List<C> result) {


            panelCharts.clear();
            for (C c : result) {

                first = new Chart()
                        .setType(Series.Type.SPLINE)
                        .setSizeToMatchContainer()

                        .setLegend(
                                new Legend()
                                        .setLayout(Legend.Layout.VERTICAL)
                                        .setAlign(Legend.Align.RIGHT)
                                        .setVerticalAlign(
                                                Legend.VerticalAlign.TOP)
                                        .setX(-10).setY(100)
                                        .setBorderWidth(0))
                        .setZoomType(Chart.ZoomType.X_AND_Y);
                first.setStyleName("chart");

                Series series = first
                        .createSeries()
                        .setName("Summer")
                        .setPoints(
                                new Number[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4,
                                        21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9,
                                        9.6 });
                first.setCredits(new Credits().setEnabled(false));
                first.addSeries(series);

                first.setChartTitleText(c.getName());



                AsyncCallback<List<M>> callbackA = new AsyncCallback<List<M>>() {
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                    }

                    public void onSuccess(List<M> result) {


                        for (M m : result) {
                            Series serie = firstChart.createSeries().setName(
                                    m.getDName());

                            first.addSeries(serie);
                     }

                    }


                };

                rpcService.getKList(ID, callbackA);
                panelCharts.add(first);
            }
            }


    };
    rpcService.getList(last, callback);
```

}

Comment: what exactly doesn't work in your code above ?

Comment: the first onsuccess work and i get the data,, but the second async onsuccess doesn'T work

Comment: do you get an exception ? maybe the `onFailure` is called. From the code itself it should work

Answer (score 0):

When I see correctly you are doing the second Async RPC inside a for loop.
This is not a good idea in my opinion.

Remember the the RPC calls are asynchronous, which means they are not blocking the execution of your script.
Your code will probably run through the whole for loop and add all the view elements to "panelCharts" before the first inner RPC call will return. There is also no guarantee on the order in which the inner RPC calls will return.

```
private void iterateElements(Iterator<C> iter){
 /*** ALL THE OTHER STUFF ***/
 AsyncCallback<List<M>> callbackA = new AsyncCallback<List<M>>() {
   public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
   }
   public void onSuccess(List<M> result) {
      /*** ALL THE OTHER STUFF ***/
      // Add view
      panelCharts.add(first);
      //If next element, do next!
      if(iter.hasNext()){
        iterateElements(iter.next());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

My suggestion would be to iterate over the list using an Iterator in an extra method like this. See how we request the next element only once the current element's RPC call is returned. This way the order is guaranteed and you add the widget to the view only if all the data is available.